# Angular, Share dynamic properties values between child components

Tags: angular, properties, siblings

I am new in Angular and I am trying to learn about the best practices. I am struggling for two days with this problem, and finally I solved it, but I am not confortable with the solution I found, I will try to explain what I did, and maybe someone knows a better solution, thanks in advance.

1 I have 3 componentes: categoryComponente (parent) and 3 children (categoryCreate, categoryUpdate and categoryList).

2 categoriesList render all the categories in the backend (endpoint), using a service who shares all these components (this is working fine):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getCategories().subscribe( (categories): any => {
      this.categories = categories.data;
    });
  }
```

3 categoryList has a (click) event:

```
<button (click)="editCategory(category._id)" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Update</button>
```

4 serviceList has an editCategory method who receives the id of the category when a user clicks on the button.

```
 editCategory( id: string ) {

// I pass the action name to show or hide the child component in the parent component html
// Example:
// <app-serviceupdate *ngIf="action === 'update'" [category]="['category']"  [action]="action" // ></app-serviceupdate>

    this.action = 'update'; 
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.categories.length; ++i) {
      if (this.categories[i]._id === id) {
            this.category = this.categories[i];
        }
    }

 
    this.service.setCurrentCategory( this.category );
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/service/update`);
  }
```

5 Now the category is a property of the shared service component (        this.service.setCurrentCategory( this.category );), and this is working fine, when I run the update form I can see the information there if I call the this.service.getCurrentCategory() (not always working good), but is it not there any other better approach in order to pass a property value between sibling components?

**For some reason, sometimes when I try to edit a category (when render the reactive form) I get this error (I think is something related with the "lifecicle":**

```
categoryComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at categoryupdateComponent.buildForm (serviceupdate.component.ts:72)
    at categoryupdateComponent.ngOnInit (serviceupdate.component.ts:39)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31910)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the if user refreshes the page, the category set by this.service.setCurrentCategory or the current "action" will be lost.

A better approach is define your routes as:

```
{ path: 'service', component: CategoryComponent, children: [
    { path:'update/:id', component: EditCategoryComponent }
    { path:'create', component: CreateCategoryComponent },
    { path:'list', component: ListCategoriesComponent },
 ]}
```

In this case in your parent component you don't need to reference the child components in template HTML. Instead just put a router-outlet and Angular will take care of loading your child component in the outlet based on the current URL.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Also there is no need to set "action" variable. Since the current action is determined by your route (which as mentioned previously is handled by angular).

Your navigation code can simple become.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/service/update/${id}`);
```

Note the :id part of the edit route, will be matched by your category id in your EditCategoryComponent. So the id becomes a part of the route/URL.

```
export class EditCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
    public category: Category;
    constructor(
        private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
        private readonly service: CategoriesService,
    ) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.paramsMap.pipe(
            switchMap((params) => this.service.getCategoryById(params.get('id')))
        ).subscribe((category) => {
             this.category = category;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to use this property (category)  in the other component "EditCategoryComponent", how can I do that? how can I send this property from "ListCategoriesComponent" to "EditCategoryComponent". I have to do this because I want to populate the edition form located in EditCategoryComponent. I know as you say i can solve the problem getting the catId by url like this category/update/5ee1bbc7d07f72adb51f8bd5, but I would like to send the whole category property from one component to the other, then I do not need to  call an endpoint inside the EditCategoryComponent.

Comment: As you see in my code example, the EditCategoryComponent can get the category from the service to populate the form (using the getCategoryById) api, which you need to implement. Basically, if you have the id, you can get the category.
This is better since it decouples the EditCategoryComponent and the ListCategoriesComponent. Also you don't need to load the ListCategoriesComponent in order to access edit. You can do directly to edit with the url, and getCategoryById would load only one category instead of loading all of them first in list before going to edit.

Comment: Yes, the solution you suggest I think it is a good one, many thanks mate!.